# Missing vertical scrollbar in web browser for vaadin 6.8.12

Tags: vaadin

I have recently built a new Vaadin widgetset for our web application. The new widgetset is based on some new addons but especially on vaadin 6.8.12.

When I deploy the ear file and start the application the right vertical scrollbar that belongs to the web browser (not a java panel or layout) is missing. The scrollbar is actually there but you are forced to drag the browser window far to the right in order to make it visible. Even though it is visible you can not scroll down as much as you need to view the lower content of the page.

This is a problem in Chrome, Firefox and Opera but for some reason Interner explorer seems to handle it just fine.

So what I want is that the browser scrollbar should be visible regardless of the size of the window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The height of a layout must be undefined for the vertical scrollbar to show up. If you set it to 100%, any content off the bottom of your browser window / tab will be hidden.

If that's not enough, please add some code to see how you made your main window layout.